# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor'

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I started to convert my asp.net core RC1 project to RC2 and faced with problem that now `IHttpContextAccessor`does not resolved.

For sake of simplicity I created new ASP.NET RC2 project using Visual Studio Template `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Framework)`. Than I added constructor for HomeController which template created for me.

```
public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
}
```

And after I start application I receive next error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'TestNewCore.Controllers.HomeController'.
>   в Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

In my real application I need to resolve `IHttpContextAccessor` in my own service class for getting access to `_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication` and to `_contextAccessor.HttpContext.User`. Everething works fine in RC1. So how can it suppose to be in RC2?

Comment: This issue has been discussed on the aspnet GitHub repository here: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793

Answer (score 378, accepted):

IHttpContextAccessor is no longer wired up by default, you have to register it yourself

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: It is worked. Also same story with `services.AddScoped<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>()`

Comment: Do we have an official recommendation about what the proper scope is? Should it be `Singleton`, `Scoped` or `Transient`?

Comment: Ah it's discussed here, and multiple people verifies it can safely be `Singleton`. https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793

Comment: When doing that, I got this error : `InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service`. Any idea ?

Comment: This is not solving the problem. I have deployed with both services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>() and services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); But both continue to return the same error.

Comment: Why is registered as singleton?

Comment: because you only need one per application and it is non trivial to create one so you don't want to be creating it over and over

Comment: Please see the next answer about using the provided extension method `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` which is preferred/recommended by Microsoft.

Comment: not working on .NET 6 ASP.NET Razor Pages template

Comment: @ajgo builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
something like this should work

Comment: @LordDraagon - thank you for the suggestion, I think I found the source of the issue on my side where in I am Injecting the HttpContextAccessor instead of IHttpContextAccessor on the constructor of my IndexModel class that causes this issue. Now everything is working on my side.

Answer (score 243):

As of .NET Core 2.1 there is an extension method that has been added to correctly register an `IHttpContextAccessor` as a singleton. See [Add helper to register IHttpContextAccessor #947](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/947). Simply add as follows in your `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

This is equivalent to:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Answer (score 18):

For .NET Core 6.0, add the following in the `Program.cs` class:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same error. I tried changing it in my ConfigureServices method also and got the error still

Answer (score 13):

For .NET Core 7.0, add the following code in the Program.cs class:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

This is equivalent to:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that comes here and made the woopsie of injecting `HttpContextAccessor` instead of `IHttpContextAccessor` in the constructor of the class where you want to use it.

This same error is thrown and the inner exception will point to the class with the problem.

Comment: I keep doing this! lol thank you for the reminder @MikaelPuusaari

Comment: No problem, glad it helped, anyone can make a whoopsie now and then and look further than needed for the fix, I did.

Comment: Thank you! What will we do without very knowledgeable people like you in this world?

Answer (score 1):

```
services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Session);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the AddHttpContextAccessor extension method from **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection**

Example:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (similar error message) even with the service registered in DI. Maybe is useful for someone, instead of using the interface I was using the actual implementation.

This doesn't work:

```cs
private readonly HttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

public YourController(HttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
{
    _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
}
```

You must use the interface:

```cs
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

public YourController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
{
    _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
}
```