# In ASP.NET Core MVC how insert the return value of a method that returns List<SelectListItem> in a Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core MVC project I need to insert the return of below method in a session to use this session in another place :

```
 public static List<SelectListItem> GetCity(int stateid)
    {
        LookupApiApi lookupApiApi = new LookupApiApi();
        Tuple<object, int> StateCities = lookupApiApi.LookupApiStateCitiesLookup(stateid);
        List<SelectListItem> listCities = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (StateCities.Item2 == 200)
        {
            List<Lookups> cityLookupResponse = (StateCities.Item1) as List<Lookups>;
            foreach (Lookups item in cityLookupResponse)
            {
                listCities.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = item.Value.ToString(),
                    Text = item.Name
                });
            }
        }
        return listCities;

    }
```

In ASP.NET Framework MVC I could insert the return value of upper action in a Session as below without any problem:

```
Session["Cities"] = GetCity(stateid);
```

But how can I do something like this in ASP.NET Core MVC? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can check this links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921275/access-session-variable-in-razor-view-net-core-2

Comment: both of this links tell me how to enable and use session in simple way in .net core. If you check my problem you will see that I need to put the output of the GetCity(stateid) in a session but I cannot!

Comment: Can you provide more details?for example what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

```
    HttpContext.Session.Set("Cities", GetCity(stateid));
```

or

```
    HttpContext.Session.Set<List<SelectListItem>>(key, result);
```

To enable use of sessions,

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            ....
            services.AddSession(options => {
                    options.IdleTimeout = <your session cookie timeout>;
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                });
            ....
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
            ....
            app.UseSession();
            ....
    }
```

and extension methods to set and get serializable objects:

```
    public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
        {
                    session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);

            return value == null ? default(T) : 
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

more at [Session and app state in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.0)