# AddHttpContextAccessor won't register

Tags: c#

I have `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in my program.cs

but keep getting the following error when I try to run the app

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate

Comment: I believe you need to use `IHttpContextAccessor` to resolve in constructors / properties, not the concrete class type.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75520898/5290908

For .NET Core 7.0, add the following code in the Program.cs class:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

This is equivalent to:

```cs
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: Have tried both suggestions, with the same error

Comment: @Robw I have just created a .NET 7 project and added `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` It works like a charm with no issue. Can you please tell me what is your current development framework and environment?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've figured it out.  The consturctor was using HttpContextAccessor instead of IHttpContextAccessor.  DOH

Comment: Please don't answer with a link to another answer. Instead, once you have enough rep, flag the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I've figured it out. The consturctor was using HttpContextAccessor instead of IHttpContextAccessor.